# IIS ARR Multiple ports

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

I'm having a hard time configuring the balance in IIS via ARR with multiple ports.
The difficulty is in working with different doors than the 80 and 443.
On the same server I have applications on port 80, 443 and 8080. I managed to make it work on port 80 and 443. When I add port 8080 it is redirected to port 443.

The structure is as follows:

```
IP PUBLIC:80   > IIS ARR > Private IP 1:80, PRIVATE IP 2:80

IP PUBLIC:443  > IIS ARR > Private IP 1:443, PRIVATE IP 2:443

IP PUBLIC:8080 > IIS ARR > Private IP 1:8080, PRIVATE IP 2:8080
```

The rules I have for url rewrite are:

```
Name: ARR_Serverfarm_loadbalance

- Match URL    
Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Wildcard
Pattern: *
MArk: Ignore Case

- Action 
Action type: Route to Server Farm
Scheme: http://
Server farm: serverfarm
Path: /{R:0}
Mark "Stop processing of subquent rules"
```

Other rule:

```
Name: Forward proxy
- Match URL
Requested URL: Does not match the Pattern
Using: Wildcards
Pattern: *
Mark: Ignore case


- Conditions
logical grouping: Match All
{HTTP_HOST} Match the Pattern * 
    
- Action
Action type: Rewrite    
Rewrite URL: http://{C:1}/{R:0}    
Mark Append query string.
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to find out what causes port 8080 to be redirected to port 443.

Comment: Hi..
Can you explain to me how to find the redirect in fiddler?
I downloaded it and installed it on my computer. I opened the browser, accessed the url domain.com:8080 and was directed to the port 80 application.
In Fiddler, I see the connection on port 8080, I click on it and on the side it shows the data, but there is no redirect information.

Comment: [Using Failed Request Tracing Rules to Troubleshoot Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr).

Comment: Good Morning.

I turned on tracing on the ARR server, but it doesn't generate the errors. I reviewed it again, so I believe there are no errors in this issue.
I'm trying to create the rule with the source on port 8080 and destination on port 8080.
If you have any further questions please let me know.

Comment: You can check the generated xml file, it will show where to redirect port 8080 to port 443.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the rule to make it clearer what I have today.

```
                <rule name="ARR_serverfarm_loadbalance" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://serverfarm/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="forward proxy" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" negate="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary, I couldn't configure port 80, 443 and 8080 on the same destination and ended up creating two different webfarms, one on 80 and 443 and another on 8080 and 8443.
After that as a final solution, I created conditions based on the URL.

Example:

```
<conditions trackAllCaptures = "true" >
<add input = "{URL}" pattern = "^/app1/( . *)"/> 
</conditions>
```